# Asp.net Website response time slow

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, web, iis-8

I created many load test on my website and response times are starting to be slow after 100 customers.

To make things clear and simple, I created dummy asp.net default website and set on load method few methods that invoke WCF service:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                WcfClientService client = new WcfClientService ();
                 //syncrhron wcf service call 
                var testMethodOne = client.callMethodOne();
                var testMethodTwo = client.callMethodTwo();
                var testMethodThree = client.callMethodTree();




        }
```

I analyzed logs on a WCF service and WCF service is returning Request for every method in short time <200 MS. 
Asp.net -> WCF is SOAP. 
What can be a bottleneck sicne WCF is returning very fast response, but web is giving me a average response of 20 seconds (above 100 customers) for A Web form that has these tree service calls.

I'm invoking load test using jmeter

I can se on my iis many requests in a queue (for website)

[image]

Site and wcf service are hosten on a IIS 8.5 (Windows Server 2012R2)

Comment: Create the client **one** time and cache it.  There is a cost to the creation of the client - it's an expensive operation compared to the actual sending/receiving of calls.

Comment: Tim, this is sample code, clientService is cached and instance is created once...not on every load...sorry for not mantioning this

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly, but you may want to try disposing of your WCF client after usage and see if that helps:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            using (var client = new WcfClientService ())
            {
               //synchronous wcf service call 
               var testMethodOne = client.callMethodOne();
               var testMethodTwo = client.callMethodTwo();
               var testMethodThree = client.callMethodTree();
            }
    }
```

There is also, by default a limit to the number of outgoing requests an ASP.net site can make, which you can change by editing the following in your web.config.

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="65535"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```